# Obtaining ERC721 interface IDs

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin

There's a related question here [ERC721: Interface ID Registration](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71560/erc721-interface-id-registration) but I couldn't get the answer I need from there.

In the OpenZeppelin ERC721 basic implementation, there's this part:

```
 // Base URI
    string private _baseURI;

    /*
     *     bytes4(keccak256('balanceOf(address)')) == 0x70a08231
     *     bytes4(keccak256('ownerOf(uint256)')) == 0x6352211e
     *     bytes4(keccak256('approve(address,uint256)')) == 0x095ea7b3
     *     bytes4(keccak256('getApproved(uint256)')) == 0x081812fc
     *     bytes4(keccak256('setApprovalForAll(address,bool)')) == 0xa22cb465
     *     bytes4(keccak256('isApprovedForAll(address,address)')) == 0xe985e9c5
     *     bytes4(keccak256('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')) == 0x23b872dd
     *     bytes4(keccak256('safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)')) == 0x42842e0e
     *     bytes4(keccak256('safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes)')) == 0xb88d4fde
     *
     *     => 0x70a08231 ^ 0x6352211e ^ 0x095ea7b3 ^ 0x081812fc ^
     *        0xa22cb465 ^ 0xe985e9c ^ 0x23b872dd ^ 0x42842e0e ^ 0xb88d4fde == 0x80ac58cd
     */
    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC721 = 0x80ac58cd;

    /*
     *     bytes4(keccak256('name()')) == 0x06fdde03
     *     bytes4(keccak256('symbol()')) == 0x95d89b41
     *     bytes4(keccak256('tokenURI(uint256)')) == 0xc87b56dd
     *
     *     => 0x06fdde03 ^ 0x95d89b41 ^ 0xc87b56dd == 0x5b5e139f
     */
    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_METADATA = 0x5b5e139f;

    /*
     *     bytes4(keccak256('totalSupply()')) == 0x18160ddd
     *     bytes4(keccak256('tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address,uint256)')) == 0x2f745c59
     *     bytes4(keccak256('tokenByIndex(uint256)')) == 0x4f6ccce7
     *
     *     => 0x18160ddd ^ 0x2f745c59 ^ 0x4f6ccce7 == 0x780e9d63
     */
    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_ENUMERABLE = 0x780e9d63;

    constructor (string memory name, string memory symbol) public {
        _name = name;
        _symbol = symbol;

        // register the supported interfaces to conform to ERC721 via ERC165
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721);
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_METADATA);
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_ENUMERABLE);
    }
```

`_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721`, `_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_METADATA`, and `_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_ENUMERABLE` are seem to be calculated (based on comments), but I'm not quite sure when this calculation needs to happen, and how?

Comment: They're not "calculated based on comments". They **were** calculated "offline" (e.g., in some JS code snippet). And they were calculated as **explained** in the comments. In the code, each one of them is set to a constant value. So this calculation doesn't "need to happen" anywhere, as it has already been conducted for you.

Comment: I see, so I have to use the same values to register the IDs? Asking because in some other contracts those values were different from the ones in the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interface calculation described in https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165 standard:

> We define the interface identifier as the XOR of all function selectors in the interface.

`_INTERFACE_ID_ERC721_METADATA` for example calculated like this:

```
 bytes4(keccak256('name()')) ^ bytes4(keccak256('symbol()')) ^ bytes4(keccak256('tokenURI(uint256)'))
```

But because all functions is part of the  https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#specification standard and interface always have same set of functions, there is no need to calculate `interfaceID` every time and most implementations using constants values.

Comment: Great answer! You might want to add the new `type(INTERFACE).interfaceId` which calculates this in Solidity 8 so you don't have to actually do this by hand (OZ is using it in their contracts now, for example: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L54)

Answer (score 1):

```
bytes4 public _INTERFACE_ID_MSNFT;
bytes4 public _INTERFACE_ID_IERC721ENUMERABLE;// should be 0x780e9d63
bytes4 public _INTERFACE_ID_IERC721METADATA; // 0x5b5e139f
bytes4 public _INTERFACE_ID_IERC721;    // 0x7aa5391d
```

https://gist.github.com/JackBekket/d1613e1aa91be56653f9cfc0b2141462

For ocasion if anyone looking for interfaceID constant's for different interfaces from open-zeppeline I wrote an utility contract, which should help with it

Comment: IERC721 id is incorrect, it should be `0x80ac58cd`.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the docs...

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

```
const _INTERFACE_ID_IERC165 = '0x01ffc9a7';
const _INTERFACE_ID_IERC721 = '0x80ac58cd';
const _INTERFACE_ID_IERC721METADATA = '0x5b5e139f';
const _INTERFACE_ID_IERC721ENUMERABLE = '0x780e9d63';
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed the IERC721 Interface ID as input for the method supportsInterface in rinkeby.etherscan.

I determined the interfaceID by adding the following method to an ERC721 contract

```
function getInterfaceIdIERC721() public pure returns (bytes4) {
    return type(IERC721).interfaceId;
}
```

And I got 0x80ac58cd as result.

After I had determined the ID then I found the question and answer here using the ID for the search. Roger mentioned links where to find the ID in the documentation (thank you for this ;-)). But I could not find the documentation nor this post without first determining the ID ;-(

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple app with the objective of making this easier, https://interfaceid.lucasgrasso.com.ar/ , you just have to paste the interface ABI, hope its useful!

Comment: Don't copy and paste the same answer multiple times. The system will flag you as a bot.